# Error while trying to automatically sign files with GPG using maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-central, gpg-signature, maven-gpg-plugin

I'm trying to deploy my project to the maven central repository but i can't resolve problem with  `Error:Sources Validation`. 
I've installed gpg and went through the instructions:
[Adding a GPG key](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-gpg-key-to-your-github-account/) and [Apache Maven signed components](http://central.sonatype.org/pages/apache-maven.html#gpg-signed-components)

When i try to run `clear deploy -e` i get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-gpg-plugin:1.5:sign (sign-artifacts) on project tarantoolorm: Exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-gpg-plugin:1.5:sign (sign-artifacts) on project tarantoolorm: Exit code: 1 at 
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212) at 
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153) at 
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145) at 
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116) at 
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80) at 
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51) at 
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128) at 
    org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307) at 
    org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193) at 
    org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106) at 
    org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863) at 
    org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288) at 
    org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199) at 
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at 
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at 
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at 
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at 
    org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289) at 
    org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229) at 
    org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415) at 
    org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356) at 
    org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47) Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Exit code: 1 at 
    org.apache.maven.plugin.gpg.GpgSigner.generateSignatureForFile(GpgSigner.java:168) at 
    org.apache.maven.plugin.gpg.AbstractGpgSigner.generateSignatureForArtifact(AbstractGpgSigner.java:205) at 
    org.apache.maven.plugin.gpg.GpgSignAttachedMojo.execute(GpgSignAttachedMojo.java:140) at 
    org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134) at 
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207) ... 21 more
```

In my `pom.xml` i have next settings:

```
 <distributionManagement>
     <snapshotRepository>
         <id>ossrh</id>
         <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
     </snapshotRepository>
     <repository>
         <id>ossrh</id>
         <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/</url>
     </repository>
 </distributionManagement>

 <build>
     <plugins>
         <plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
             <configuration>
                 <source>1.8</source>
                 <target>1.8</target>
             </configuration>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>2.2.1</version>
             <executions>
                 <execution>
                     <id>attach-sources</id>
                     <goals>
                         <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                     </goals>
                 </execution>
             </executions>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>1.5</version>
             <executions>
                 <execution>
                     <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                     <phase>verify</phase>
                     <goals>
                         <goal>sign</goal>
                     </goals>
                 </execution>
             </executions>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>2.9.1</version>
             <executions>
                 <execution>
                     <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                     <goals>
                         <goal>jar</goal>
                     </goals>
                 </execution>
             </executions>
         </plugin>
     </plugins>
 </build>
```

Also, i added some properties into `settings.xml`:

```
 <profiles>
     <profile>
         <id>ossrh</id>
         <activation>
             <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
         </activation>
         <properties>
             <gpg.executable>gpg</gpg.executable>
             <gpg.passphrase></gpg.passphrase>
         </properties>
     </profile>
 </profiles>
```

But it doesn't help.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: First try to upgrade maven-gpg-plugin to version 1.6

Comment: Now i get this: ```Unable to execute gpg command: Error while executing process. Cannot run program "gpg.exe": CreateProcess error=2```, but it is very strange, because i've installed gpg4win

Comment: Try to run with `mvn -X ...` and redirect the output into a file like `mvn -X .. >x.log` and try to see if there are more information about the issue related to maven-gpg-plugin...Maybe the gpg.exe is not on `PATH` ?

Comment: The problem was in incorrect PATH and then in default public key. Now it works ^_^

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, I used the full path instead of "gpg"
[image]